# Bootstrapping data into webpack bundled javascript from html

Tags: javascript, html, scala, reactjs, webpack

I've recently converted a React app from a globals-everywhere script-tag-per-js-file setup into a bundled webpack app (great!).

However, in the app originally I was able to expose global init functions in the scripts and then have rendered calls in the generated html server from my Scala Play backend. For instance

```
// Component.js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <div> {this.props.myData} </div>
    }
}
initComponent(data) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MyComponent myData={data} />
    ) 
}
```

And then in the backend:

```
// ComponentPage.scala.html
...
<script> 
  $(() => initComponent(@scala.serverVariable.getData(currentUser))
</script>
```

Now that my javascript is bundled (and eventually minified/uglified), I don't have any way for the scala backend to know the mangled/eventual name of the function to call. Is there a way to tell webpack to keep certain functions global? Is there a better pattern to use to bootstrap the serverside data into the react component?

Here are two approaches I've considered:

- I could make it a loading/complete style component, where there's a spinner and then an ajax call to the server to get the correct data, but since I already have the data available at render time, I'd rather not incur an extra round-trip from client to server.
- I can include the data in a  tag with data-attributes and fetch it onDocumentReady, but the serialization/deserialization has limitations for complex objects and this feels quite hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply attach the function to the `window` object. This will prevent name mangling.

```
window.initComponent = function(data) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent myData={data} />
  ) 
}
```

Similarly (for explicitness):

```
// ComponentPage.scala.html
...
<script> 
  $(() => window.initComponent(@scala.serverVariable.getData(currentUser))
</script>
```